# Encountering Deployment Error with AWS CDK: Despite Bootstrapping

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

I encounter an issue when deploy cdk app using command 'cdk deploy'. The error is following.

```
✨  Synthesis time: 8.02s

NewlamStack:  start: Building d61d5a108f7fbfde3ad135dcd054169e71324cf2ab736703bdda4a735c700f53:current_account-current_region
NewlamStack:  success: Built d61d5a108f7fbfde3ad135dcd054169e71324cf2ab736703bdda4a735c700f53:current_account-current_region
NewlamStack:  start: Building 062df176a6bc7fc148dc7b1c87268561e8bb53da619aefeea095db03c59653ea:current_account-current_region
NewlamStack:  success: Built 062df176a6bc7fc148dc7b1c87268561e8bb53da619aefeea095db03c59653ea:current_account-current_region
NewlamStack:  start: Publishing d61d5a108f7fbfde3ad135dcd054169e71324cf2ab736703bdda4a735c700f53:current_account-current_region
NewlamStack:  start: Publishing 062df176a6bc7fc148dc7b1c87268561e8bb53da619aefeea095db03c59653ea:current_account-current_region
NewlamStack:  fail: No bucket named 'cdk-hnb659fds-assets-024048322020-us-east-1'. Is account 024048322020 bootstrapped?
NewlamStack:  fail: No bucket named 'cdk-hnb659fds-assets-024048322020-us-east-1'. Is account 024048322020 bootstrapped?

 ❌ Deployment failed: Error: Failed to publish asset d61d5a108f7fbfde3ad135dcd054169e71324cf2ab736703bdda4a735c700f53:current_account-current_region
    at Deployments.publishSingleAsset (/home/burkiwsl/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.1/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:433:11467)
    at async Object.publishAsset (/home/burkiwsl/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.1/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:433:196681)
    at async /home/burkiwsl/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.1/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:433:180800

Failed to publish asset d61d5a108f7fbfde3ad135dcd054169e71324cf2ab736703bdda4a735c700f53:current_account-current_region
```

i tried to bootstrap account using command **'cdk bootstrap'**. but above error is still persists. I'm using **nvm** **version 0.38.0, node version v18.19.1, cdk version 2.133.0 (build dcc1e75), aws cli version 'aws-cli/2.15.32 Python/3.11.8 Linux/5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 exe/x86_64.ubuntu.22 prompt/off' and Python 3.10.12.**
**Note: I'm using WSL on Windows10**

I bootstrap account with command 'cdk bootstrap aws://my-account-ID/my-account-region'.

Comment: Did you bootstrap the correct account and region (`024048322020`/`us-east-1` in this case)?

Comment: yes. I bootstrap account with command 'cdk bootstrap aws://my-account-ID/my-account-region'.

Comment: Could you share the stack? The `current_account-current_region` in this line here tells me that something is wrong with the stack: `Failed to publish asset d61d5a108f7fbfde3ad135dcd054169e71324cf2ab736703bdda4a735c700f53:current_account-current_region`

Comment: Also, when you log in to aws console, can you see that bucket `cdk-hnb659fds-assets-024048322020-us-east-1` in S3?

Comment: I resolved this error by deleting previous cdk stake from cloudFormation. But did not understand what was the issue with previous cdk stake which i created (deployed) just 2 weeks ago. Thanks for all

Comment: @imranburki please could you post your last comment as an "answer" to this question?

Comment: @DMalan I would but i  couldn't find any answer section for this question. Maybe it's because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time)